# Alloy-ui diagram-builder method overwriting

Tags: user-interface, diagram, alloy-ui

My question is quite simple, how can I overwrite the method connectEnd from the aui-diagram-builder-impl.js ?

There is no problem to overwrite the methods from aui-diagram-builder.js. I importing the aui-diagram-builder-impl.js file in my index.html but it still not working.

I overwrite the methods like that:

```js
Y.DiagramBuilder.editConnector = function (connector) {
                    //some code
                };
```

and it works, but this is not...

```html
Y.DiagramBuilder.connectEnd = function (connector) {
                    //some code
                };
```

Some ideas, anybody ?

Answer (score 1):

[`DiagramBuilder` has no `connectEnd()` function.](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.DiagramBuilder.html) Perhaps you are looking for [`DiagramNodeCondition.connectEnd()`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.DiagramNodeCondition.html#method_connectEnd)?